# Pull comments field from approval process to report

Tags: approval-process

How to pull the comments field as attached in image below into the report. The basic idea is the value 'Need more action' (from users) in the comments field is shown in the report to be printed.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. Specifically (and use [edit]), _which report_?

Comment: Sorry, I mean custom reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At moment this [feature](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l7s0AAA) is unavailable.  As a workaround, you can access the approver's comments via the ProcessSteps with the help of trigger.

Create field update to check copy comment field on final approval/rejection action.  This field would trigger approval comments to copy on the opportunity.  Create new(long text, checkbox) fields on opportunity.

```
//Example of opportunity 
       
trigger approver on opportunity (before update) {

if(trigger.isUpdate){
List<Opportunity> opptyList =  [Select id,(Select Id,IsPending,ProcessInstanceId, TargetObjectId, StepStatus,OriginalActorId,ActorId,RemindersSent,Comments,IsDeleted,CreatedDate, CreatedById, SystemModstamp FROM ProcessSteps ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) from Opportunity WHERE Id IN : Trigger.new];
            if(opptyList.size() > 0){
            for(Opportunity opp : opptyList){
            for(Opportunity opp1 : Trigger.new) {
                if(opp.id == opp1.id && opp1.copycomment__c) {
                if (opp.ProcessSteps.size() > 0) {
                opp1.Approver_Comment__c = opp.ProcessSteps[0].Comments;
                opp1.copycomment__c = false;
            }
            }
            }
           }
         }   
    }  
}
```

Also, you might want to check similar reference [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/update-approvers-comment-as-field-update).

Thanks

Comment: This Apex code uses an extremely inefficient N^2 "matrix search". You don't need to iterate over Opportunities twice or check the size of the Opportunity list  - use a Map.

Comment: Means I need to create new field for the object first right? before I create update field in approval/ rejection action? @Vinay

Comment: Yes and this is an alternate workaround also check if you can use any existing fields @WanNurAtiqahWanAhmadYusri....  Thank you David

Comment: Thank you. I got it